# Can you factor functions with a mixture of complex conjugates?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are these equal or am I saying this right? I'm just worried about the complex conjugate being mixed in.

$$f(x)+\overline g \overline(\overline x) = (f+\overline g)(x)$$

Note, the overline is over `g(x)` and then once factored, over `g`.

If they are not equal, is there anything similar that is?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking about $f(x) + \overline{g(x)} = (f + \overline g)(x)$?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly it. I couldn't get `\overline` to go over it all.

Comment: Seems okay, if you've got $\overline g(x) = \overline{g(x)}$.